# Visual Studio C++ and OpenMPI in windows: missing files.h

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-express, openmpi

I've just correctly installed Visual Studio Express C++ and OpenMPI.
I've added the path to PATH variable:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenMPI_v1.5.5-win32\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
```

and I've written a simple program in MPI on visual c++ express.
The problem is that when I try to compile from prompt dos

```
mpicxx -o mpi mpi01.cpp
```

it tells me that there are a lot of missing files.h (no such file od directory) which are all inside
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
But, as I've just said, I've included this in PATH.
Why does it miss them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "prompt dos" should be the one you get when you launch the Visual Studio "Developper Command prompt". Shortcut located in your Start Menu -> Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools

Comment: Thanks! Another soulution could be to digit "vcvars32.bat" in the prompt dos every time the pc is booted, right?

Comment: @LoryLory I don't think that will do it, because that will not impact subsequent prompt launch. Better to create/copy your own shortcut to cmd.exe, based on the one in the answer. By the way, do you confirm that your compilation is fine, now?

Comment: Yes I confirm! It seems to work...can I ask if you would be so kind to tell me how I could start windows programming? In my degree we only studied unix/linux programming and I think I should know windows too studying by myself

Comment: If my answer was the good one, accept it then :-) I see in your profile that you never accept answer. why is that? I can't give advise with so so little information. It depends what kind of studies?

Comment: Ehm...I think I have a little problem. I didn't know, up to now when you've told, that I had to accept answers...I thought I had only to give "+1"...how I can do it?

Comment: and what am I supposed to tell him? :S

Comment: @LoryLory I think we can't talk about "how I could start windows programming?" just in Stackoverflow commments.